# Hidden parameter in C++ function call

Tags: c++, assembly, c++17, calling-convention, abi

I just watched Jason Turners `C++ Code Smells` talk from the last **CppCon'19** and paused at 7.37m, where he talks about output parameters.

https://youtu.be/f_tLQl0wLUM?t=457

The function in question (see [GodBolt](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/PjKz75) link), has a return value. His question is, how many parameters does this function take and the answer is 1. I am trying to understand what that means.

```
std::string get_value();

int main()
{
    const auto value = get_value();
}
```

The resulting (and interesting part of that) assembly is this:

```
...
mov     rdi, rsp
...
```

He said `rdi` is the register for the first parameter, but I don't know what the point of this code piece is. Does that mean the compiler created a hidden [out] parameter instead of the return value? Could someone elaborate what that means?

Comment: It's passing a pointer to the return-value object because it's too big to return in a register (and/or non-trivially-copyable).  See the x86-64 System V ABI for details, or various SO questions.

Comment: The function takes a parameter which specifies where the function should write the return value

Comment: Thanks for the explanation!